# How to design a 100vh layout with fixed header, dynamic main content height and scrollable items using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to design a layout with flexbox that meets the following criteria:

- wrapper element is a flex container, height is 100vh - let's call it modal
- modal has two children: a `header` and a `main` element
- `header` will have content based calculated height (line height of the texts + padding + margin)
- `main` will have dynamic height based on the following rules:
- 1. `main` height should always be equal to modal height (100vh) - header height
- 2. if `main`'s children height is higher than `main`'s calculated height, set overflow: scroll on the children
- 3. if `children`'s height is lower than the `main`'s calculated height, set the children height as filling the available space.

I have provided the following example, you can test it here https://play.tailwindcss.com/n6iRsbXnAH

In essence, in the example, all I want is to "force" green div to overflow instead of making the whole page to overflow.

Thank you!

```html
<div class="modal flex h-screen flex-col bg-red-500">
  <header class="h-36 flex-shrink-0 bg-blue-400">Header</header>
  <main class="flex flex-grow flex-row bg-yellow-500">
    <div class="flex max-h-full w-1/3 flex-col">
      <p class="flex-shrink-0">title</p>
      <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="h-screen bg-green-300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.h-screen {
  height: 100vh;
}

.h-36 {
  height: 9rem;
}

.max-h-full {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.w-1\/3 {
  width: 33.333333%;
}

.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bg-red-500 {
  background-color: rgb(239 68 68);
}

.bg-blue-400 {
  background-color: rgb(96 165 250);
}

.bg-yellow-500 {
  background-color: rgb(234 179 8);
}

.bg-green-300 {
  background-color: rgb(134 239 172);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `min-height: 0` to `main` element everything works as expected. Check here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rojtjSWbqq

```html
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col bg-red-500">
  <header class="h-36 flex-shrink-0 bg-blue-400">Header</header>
  <main class="flex min-h-0 flex-grow flex-row bg-yellow-500">
    <div class="flex w-1/3 flex-col">
      <p class="flex-shrink-0">title</p>
      <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="h-screen bg-green-300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex w-1/3 flex-col">
      <p class="flex-shrink-0">title</p>
      <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex w-1/3 flex-col">
      <p class="flex-shrink-0">title</p>
      <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="h-screen bg-green-300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.h-screen {
  height: 100vh;
}

.h-36 {
  height: 9rem;
}

.min-h-0 {
  min-height: 0px;
}

.w-1\/3 {
  width: 33.333333%;
}

.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bg-red-500 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-blue-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(96 165 250 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-yellow-500 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(234 179 8 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.bg-green-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(134 239 172 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is to:

- give the  a `position relative`
- the container of the green element gets: `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; overflow-y: hidden;`

And that should be it...

Basically all containers will always grow, unless you tell it not to. Since you have a 100vh layout with flex-containers already in place you can just set the green container absolute.

If you want to have more content with different flow in the yellow area you may want to set the green element absolute inside its container (take care to set `position relative` to the container of the absolute child)